# Proving orthogonality of two antennas intuition

Tags: antenna, patch-antenna

I am reading this article: *[The Design of Shared Aperture Antennas Consisting
of Differently Sized Elements](https://easyupload.io/wu0zqi)*.

I have there two antennas which, I was told, have orthogonal polarization, but when I try to simulate them separately I see both of them having the same fringing fields shape and the same farfield radiation shape. Where did I go wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: These appear to be traditional 'F' or dipole antennas, for which E-polarization is parallel to the long axis of the element(s); who said otherwise? Note: XYZ axis arrows aren't visible in the second so it's not obvious if the two are oriented orthogonally.

Comment: Hello Tim, In the article attached in the main post ,they presented the following structure shown in the links bellow
In the article they say that these antennas are with orthogonal polarization.
Could you please explain to me why  their E-fields will be orthogonal?
(so they will not interfere one another)
Thanks
https://ibb.co/yWsKDq3
https://ibb.co/gzkDcFy

Comment: Oh are those different scale anyway? Just glancing through the paper, I only see one (circular patch antenna). Your models/screenshots aren't clear enough to tell what's going on.

Comment: Hello Tim, its a rectangual patch antenna near inverted L  antenna,why they are in orthogonal polarization?
Is it possible ?
Thanks.